# Select sums and last record in query

Tags: sql, firebird

This is code for calculating rests of goods with 2 date period:

rest=start quantity at first date+ incomes in period- sales in period.

Is it possible change dt1 derived table so it gets the income price of the last income? Not sum but price of last income?

My desired output is get result table with these columns:
goods_id, goods, last_income_price, sold_qnt, rest

Example data:

table **goods**:

| goods_id | goods |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | good1 |
| 2 | good2 |
| 3 | good3 |
| 4 | good4 |

table **incomes:**

| income_id | income_dt | qnt | income_price | goods_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 07.08.2021 | 100 | 1.5 | 1 |
| 2 | 01.05.2022 | 120 | 1.4 | 1 |
| 3 | 05.06.2022 | 200 | 1.45 | 1 |
| 4 | 02.10.2022 | 50 | 10 | 2 |
| 5 | 07.08.2021 | 100 | 1.6 | 1 |
| 6 | 01.05.2022 | 120 | 1.55 | 1 |
| 7 | 05.06.2023 | 200 | 1.38 | 1 |
| 8 | 01.08.2023 | 600 | 10.5 | 2 |
| 9 | 07.08.2021 | 100 | 12 | 3 |
| 10 | 01.05.2022 | 120 | 15.2 | 4 |
| 11 | 05.06.2022 | 200 | 12.3 | 3 |
| 12 | 10.11.2022 | 250 | 15.5 | 4 |

table **sales:**

| sale_id | sale_dt | qnt | goods_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.08.2021 | 20 | 1 |
| 2 | 15.05.2022 | 10 | 1 |
| 3 | 25.06.2022 | 5 | 1 |
| 4 | 20.10.2022 | 100 | 2 |
| 5 | 17.08.2021 | 10 | 1 |
| 6 | 01.05.2022 | 15 | 1 |
| 7 | 05.06.2022 | 30 | 1 |
| 8 | 01.08.2023 | 30 | 2 |
| 9 | 07.08.2021 | 10 | 3 |
| 10 | 01.05.2022 | 8 | 4 |
| 11 | 05.06.2022 | 20 | 3 |
| 12 | 10.11.2022 | 25 | 4 |

**expected output:**

sales in time interval (from 01.01.2022 to 15.08.2023) and rests at 15.08.2023

| goods_id | goods | last_income_price | sold_qnt | rest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | goods1 | 1.38 | 90 | 750 |
| 2 | goods2 | 10.5 | 130 | 520 |
| 3 | goods3 | 12.3 | 30 | 270 |
| 4 | goods4 | 15.5 | 33 | 337 |

I'm using Firebird 3.

db tables:

- goods: goods_id, goods...
- incomes: income_id, income_dt, qnt, income_price,  goods_id...
- sales: sale_id, income_id, sale_dt, qnt, goods_id...

```sql
SELECT
    g.goods ,
    g.goods_id,
    coalesce(dt2.startqnt,0) as startqnt,
    coalesce(dt2.income,0)as income_qnt,
    coalesce(dt2.sales,0)as sales_qnt,
    coalesce(dt2.rest,0) as rest

FROM goods g
LEFT JOIN
   (select                                                                          --dt2
      goods_id,
      coalesce(sum(startincome),0) as startincome,
      coalesce(sum(startsale),0) as startsale,
      sum(coalesce(startincome,0)-coalesce(startsale,0)) as startqnt,
   
      coalesce(sum(income_qnt),0) as income_qnt,
      coalesce(sum(sale_qnt),0) as sales_qnt,
      sum(coalesce(startincome,0)-coalesce(startsale,0)+coalesce(income_qnt,0)-coalesce(sale_qnt,0)) as rest

    from(
         select                                                                     --dt1
           i.goods_id,
           sum(case when i.income_dt<:d1 then coalesce(i.qnt,0)  end) as startincome,
           0 as startsale,
           sum(case when (cast(i.income_dt as date)>=:d1) and (cast(i.income_dt as date)<=:d2) then coalesce(i.qnt,0) end) as income_qnt,
           0 as sale
        from income i
       where i.income_dt<=:d2
        group by goods_id
    union all
         select
           s.goods_id,
           0,
           sum(case when (cast(s.sale_dt as date) <:d1) then coalesce(s.qnt,0) end) as startsale,
           0,
           sum(case when (cast(s.sale_dt as date) >=:d1) and (cast(s.sale_dt as date)<=:d2) then coalesce(s.qnt,0) end) as sale_qnt
        from sale s , income i
        where
          s.sale_dt<=:d2 and
          s.income_id=i.income_id
        group by goods_id
    ) dt1
   group by goods_id )dt2
on g.goods_id=dt2.goods_id
order by goods
```

Comment: Please provide example data and expected results for that sample data. Preparing a dbfiddle would be helpful to.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I edited post and add example data and expected result in it. Please see my edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last income price for each product, you'll need to add logic to fetch the latest income date for each product and then join that back with the income table to get the associated price.

Below is a modified version of your SQL that should achieve the desired results:

```
SELECT
    g.goods,
    g.goods_id,
    coalesce(dt2.startqnt,0) as startqnt,
    coalesce(dt2.income_qnt,0) as income_qnt,
    coalesce(dt2.sales_qnt,0) as sales_qnt,
    coalesce(dt2.rest,0) as rest,
    coalesce(dt2.last_income_price,0) as last_income_price

FROM goods g
LEFT JOIN
   (select
      goods_id,
      coalesce(sum(startincome),0) as startincome,
      coalesce(sum(startsale),0) as startsale,
      sum(coalesce(startincome,0)-coalesce(startsale,0)) as startqnt,
      coalesce(sum(income_qnt),0) as income_qnt,
      coalesce(sum(sale_qnt),0) as sales_qnt,
      sum(coalesce(startincome,0)-coalesce(startsale,0)+coalesce(income_qnt,0)-coalesce(sale_qnt,0)) as rest,
      li.price as last_income_price

    from(
         select
           i.goods_id,
           sum(case when i.income_dt<:d1 then coalesce(i.qnt,0) end) as startincome,
           0 as startsale,
           sum(case when (cast(i.income_dt as date)>=:d1) and (cast(i.income_dt as date)<=:d2) then coalesce(i.qnt,0) end) as income_qnt,
           0 as sale_qnt
        from income i
        where i.income_dt<=:d2
        group by goods_id

    union all

         select
           s.goods_id,
           0,
           sum(case when (cast(s.sale_dt as date) <:d1) then coalesce(s.qnt,0) end) as startsale,
           0,
           sum(case when (cast(s.sale_dt as date) >=:d1) and (cast(s.sale_dt as date)<=:d2) then coalesce(s.qnt,0) end) as sale_qnt
        from sale s , income i
        where s.sale_dt<=:d2 and s.income_id=i.income_id
        group by goods_id
    ) dt1

    -- Get the last income price for each product
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
          i.goods_id,
          i.price
      FROM income i
      WHERE i.income_dt = (
          SELECT MAX(i2.income_dt)
          FROM income i2
          WHERE i2.goods_id = i.goods_id
      )
    ) li on dt1.goods_id = li.goods_id

   group by goods_id, li.price
) dt2
on g.goods_id = dt2.goods_id
order by g.goods
```